# Check if there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $B=P^{-1}AP$

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, matrix-congruences

I want to check if for matrices

$$
A =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
B =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
        3 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $B=P^{-1}AP$.

Since $P^{-1}=P^T$, this is equivalent to checking that $B=P^TAP$ (which is the definition of congruence). My first idea was to cast this as a bilinear form:

$$A=G(h;st)=\left(M(id)_{st}^{\mathcal{A}}\right)^TG(h;\mathcal{A})M(id)_{st}^{\mathcal{A}}$$
where $B=G(h;\mathcal{A})$, $h$ is a bilinear form and $st$ is the standard basis. If we knew $\mathcal{A}$, we would be done. However, I don't see a straightforward way to find this basis. I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Can you prove that $P^{-1}AP$ must be symmetric?

Comment: As a consequence of the spectral theorem, symmetric matrices are orthogonally similar if and only if they have the same eigenvalues

Comment: With $P$ equal to a certain permutation matrix, we can find that
$$
P^{-1}AP = \pmatrix{1\\&2\\&&1&1\\&&1&1}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is symmetric and $P$ is orthogonal, $P^{-1}AP$ must be symmetric, but $B$ is not symmetric, hence we can't get such a $P$.